# Bootstrap collapses too fast

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

My Bootstrap navbar breaks into 2 lines whereas there is some space left:

[image]

In the navbar, I have also navbar-right:

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a class="txt-c" href="/home/"><p><i class="fa fa-bandcamp"></i></p>Home</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="/sample/"><p><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></p>Demo</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="/sample/"><p><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></p>Notice</a></li>
            <li class=""><a class="txt-c" href="/contact/"><p><i class="fa fa-envelope-open"></i></p>Contact</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="/sample/"><p><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></p>Purchase</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class=""><a class="nav-signin" href="/signin">Log in</a></li>
            <li class=""><a class="nav-signup" href="/signup">Sign up</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">EN<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="nav-lang" href="?lang=fr"><span class="pad-l-10 fnt-rob pad-t-10">Français</span></a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

How to make the navbar-nav and the navbar-right be closest before collapsing ?

Comment: Don't wrap login and signup in a new list?

Comment: But I like that having them at the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question it's quite simple, just override the `.navbar-right` rule from bootstrap. In my example i inserted `margin-right:150px;`

https://jsfiddle.net/f7pw4ouk/

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did like that and does not breaks into 2 rows anymore:
`@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .navbar-right {
        margin-right:-60px;
    }
}
` Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write new media rules or rewrite Bootstrap breakpoints

I tried to reproduce your issue

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class=""><a class="nav-signin" href="/signin">Log in</a></li>
                <li class=""><a class="nav-signup" href="/signup">Sign up</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">EN<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="nav-lang" href="?lang=fr"><span class="pad-l-10 fnt-rob pad-t-10">Français</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Example css:

```
@media (min-width: 550 px) {
    .navbar-nav > li {
        float: left;
    }
    .navbar-right {
        float: right!important;
        margin-right: -15 px;
    }
    .nav {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        left: auto;
        display: block;
        background: #000000;
    }
}
```

I tried to save the example  http://www.bootply.com/MvKdHiXkyW#

Comment: Yes ok, It is too bad to loose the space of the red arrow I have drawn. But I will do that if there is no other solution. Thank you.